# How to check if mod_security is activated with PHP (without curl)

Tags: php, mod-security

Is there a way to know if mod_security is activated on an apache server using PHP? (without curl)

Comment: Do you mean the local server (the one the PHP script is running on) or a remote server?

Comment: the local server then, thanks

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could try is using apache_get_modules to discover what modules Apache currently has enabled.  Of course this approach will only work on an Apache server and not on other popular HTTP servers.

```
var_dump (in_array ('mod_security', apache_get_modules ()));
```